# WP7: Move a control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, drag

I'm tring to move a button in WP7 using `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseLeftButtonUp`. The problem is when I move it (by mouse) it looks unstable and I can't explain it.

```
bool clicked = false;
private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(sender as Button);
    double margin1, margin2;
    margin1 = p.X - (button1.ActualWidth / 2) + 12;

    // 12 is the distance between left of the page and the content panel
    margin2 = p.Y - (button1.ActualHeight / 2) + 161;

    // 161 is the distance between top of the page and the content panel
    button1.Margin = new Thickness(margin1, margin2, 0, 0);
}

private void button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    clicked = true;
}

private void button1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    clicked = false;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use the ManipulationDelta event instead. The event gives you how many pixels the mouse has moved since the last time the event was triggered. Then you can just add this value to the current margin of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) control as your `Button` control's container. Then you can specify `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` values on your `Button` and move it properly, without having to play with the size and margin. See [here](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/10/26/wpf-how-to-move-elements-at-runtime.aspx) for an example related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! That helps alot. What I finally use is :                `private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
            //gets the point inside the canvas
            if (p.X >= 0 && p.X <= MyCanvas.ActualWidth)
                ButtonToMove.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, p.X - (ButtonToMove.ActualWidth / 2));
            if (p.Y >= 0 && p.Y <= MyCanvas.ActualHeight)
                ButtonToMove.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, p.Y - (ButtonToMove.ActualHeight / 2));
        }`

Comment: @Downvoter - Please explain the downvote, as it makes no sense given the answer was accepted. If you disagree with the answer, comment to explain the disagreement.